# angular getting blank screen after reload on electron

Tags: angular, electron

Copy from [github#28289](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/28289)

#### Electron Version

12.0.1

#### What operating system are you using?

Windows

#### Operating System Version

version 20H2

#### What arch are you using?

x64

#### Last Known Working Electron version

I don't know

#### Expected Behavior

reload webpage like broweser

#### Actual Behavior

Getting blank screen after reload

#### Testcase Gist URL

https://gist.github.com/clark-97/35b1bda0acfc604c714178795e9659a9

I guess it releted [github#14978](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/14978) which is closed.
steps to reproduce

```sh
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new electron-test
cd electron-test
npm install electron --save-dev
npm install electron-builder --save-dev
nano src/index.html
nano index.js
nano package.json
ng build
npm run build
```

then I run release/win-unpacked/electron-test.exe, it load webpage normally. after click CTRL+R, it geting blank

the two don't work
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/14978#issuecomment-510092294
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/14978#issuecomment-610773951

the two work, but still get blank in short, then load page normally, and they are not friendly angualr router, after reload webpage, the page will go to default router, not original page
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/14978#issuecomment-535191746
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/14978#issuecomment-785097599